# setErrors on matInput not working Angular material 10

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-validation

Trying to set the error on the matInput, but the input is not red, however the form is invalid.

```
<input matInput [formControlName]="field.formControlName" [placeholder]="field.componentProperty.placeHolder"
        [type]="field?.componentProperty?.attrType" [ngStyle]="field.componentProperty.componentStyle"
        [ngClass]="field.componentProperty.componentCss"
        [required]="group.get(field.formControlName).errors !== null && group.get(field.formControlName).errors.required">
```

Setting the error to the form.

```
this.form.get("confirmpassword").setErrors({'incorrect': true});
```

Comment: Can you share the template code including the form element?

Comment: I have done the reusable component, repo can be found here https://github.com/anandjaisy/Angular-Dynamic-Form-Builder/tree/master/src/app/component/input/input-error and demo can be view as https://anandjaisy.github.io/Angular-Dynamic-Form-Builder/